# How to upload a video from iOS device to Django server

Tags: python, ios, django

How to upload a video from iOS device to Django server and after to save it to a folder in mp4 format. 
I've tried something. This is my iOS Code:

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAddress]];

NSData *postData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self.movieURL absoluteString]];

[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"name"];
[request addData:postData withFileName:@"testt.mov" andContentType:@"video/quicktime" forKey:@"file"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request setCompletionBlock:^
 {
     NSLog(@"ResponseString:%@",[request responseString]);
 }];
[request setFailedBlock:^
 {
     NSLog(@"Error");
 }];

[request startSynchronous];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this is my python code:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
file = forms.FileField()


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=['POST'])

    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST.get('name'), request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"Status": 0}, sort_keys=True))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"Status": 1}, sort_keys=True))


def handle_uploaded_file(file, path=''):
    # filename = file._get_name()
    destination_file = open('%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + 'test.mp4'), 'wb+')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        destination_file.write(chunk)
    destination_file.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, till now I've made the picker controller that returns me the path of the video in my device and I'm trying to convert it to data and send it to my python/django server and here I want it to recieve it and save to my desktop/folder the video file from my device. The problem was that it crases at django server but i've solve it with -> form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) . Now form.is_valid() is not valid because it doesn't fine any data.

Comment: I've changed my iOS code with 
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"title"];
    [request setFile:urlString forKey:@"file"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];

Now it give me: -> Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it.

Here is the iOS code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSString *urlString=[urlvideo path];

NSString *str = serverAddress;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",videoName.text] forKey:@"title"];
[request setFile:urlString forKey:@"file"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];

NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %@",[request responseString]);

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Django Code:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
         return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=['POST'])

form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if form.is_valid():
    handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], request.POST.get('title'))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"Status": 0}, sort_keys=True))
else:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"Status": 1}, sort_keys=True))


def handle_uploaded_file(file, string, path=''):
    destination_file = open('%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + string), 'wb+')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        destination_file.write(chunk)
    destination_file.close()
```

Problem was at django, didn't find the file.